# Get a key from an JSOn object inside another JSON object only knowing it's position

Tags: php, json

So I have the following JSON Object as an example:

```
 {

  "employees": {
    "employee300": {
      "number" : "example",
      "Name" : "example",
      "position" : 1
    },
    "employee456": {"number" : "example",
      "Name" : "example",
      "position" : 2},
    "employee120":{"number" : "example",
      "Name" : "example",
      "position" : 3}
}
}
```

I only have the position and I want to get the employee's id. For example, I have the position number that is 2 and I need to get the id that is "employee456".

I know there are a lot of key functions in PHP, but I would like to know how I can make my code work in my scenario.
I can also convert the json to an array if there is a solution to it that way.

Comment: How did you parse the JSON in PHP? `json_decode`? As array or as object? Show us the relevant code. It's always useful.

Comment: I am parsing it with json_decode and I am doing it as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to do this in JS or PHP, going to assume the latter.

```
<?php function get_employee_at_pos($employees, $pos)
{
    foreach ($employees as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['position'] == $pos) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `var keys = Object.keys(obj)` to get the keys, then use the `myobject[keys[1]]`. (1 corresponds to `position - 1`).

EDIT:  in php

`$keys = array_keys(myobject);` and use `$myobject[$keys[1]]`

EDIT 2: in php, you need to load the json in an array

```
$myjson = json_decode(file_get_contents("yourfile.json"), true); // loads yourfile.json and converts to a php array.
```

Comment: Isn't this half in JS?

Comment: @MarkKevin: Updated to php

Comment: @Rudie: he gets its object from a json, just need to use `json_decode("json...", true);` to force the conversion in array.